# Quick Access to portion of data inside a dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm

For example, if I have got millions of records inside a dictionary with the form of
`{(1,2):3,(2,3):4,(3:2):5...xmillion}`
That's a tuple as a key and with a corresponding value

What I would like to do is get the data of which the value of tuple[1] = 2
One of my approach is

```
    for item, value in dict.iteritems():
      if item[1] == 2:
        Do operations here...
```

This is a slow approach, is there a better algorithm for doing this to make it fast?
Like.. so I don't have to go through million of the items

Comment: Do you have any flexibility to change the dict structure? Storing it as {1: {2: 3}, 2: {3: 4}} etc would make that sort of access a lot easier.

Comment: Else you can also maintain another hashtable to make lookup fast if you need frequent lookups.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Are you sure that is the structure you mean? OP wants `item[1]==2` not `item[0]==2`.

Comment: Or from `{(a,b):c}` to `{b:{(a,b):c}}`. This would make your selection for `(item, value for item, value in D.iteritems() if item[1] == 2)` require only `D[2].iteritems()`.

Comment: Or have another additional hashtable like {1:(2, ...), 2:(3, ...) ...}. This would only take up as much as memory as needed and you can have fast lookups.

Comment: Im trying not to create a new dict

Comment: Maybe... Using some kind of algorithm like sorting the keys according item[1] will enhance the performance in some cases

Comment: However, for the worst case is still have to run through the whole dict

Comment: Duplicate data make the program looks not perfect enough, although i know sometimes time and space must have trade offs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a dictionary of tuples as key, you would have to iterate through all the keys to find
those with `key[1] == 2`. There is no other alternative to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If *all you have* is the dictionary of `{(a,b):c}` then no, you can't do any better: since you don't know which keys have `b=2` you have to look at all of them.

If you are building the dictionary yourself, you can separate out the tuples with `b=2` at that stage so you don't have to search for them again. You could either store them in a separate dictionary (just the items `{(a,2):c}`) or rewrite the structure of the dictionary you have (e.g. `{b:{(a,b):c}}`).